# How to know from which instance of Fragment the setOnCheckedChangeListener is called?

Tags: android

I have a main activity in which i have to display 3out of 12 questions in each screen (which are saved in sql database) and with radio buttons Yes and No .
So i made a fragment class and call it thrice in my main activity .
On my next button i create and intent of my main class .
hence with one fragment i populate 12 questions in 4 screens .

Now , when i press the radio button , i want to see for which question the radio button is clicked and then calculate the score (each question has separate score. this is also mapped in my sqlite database against each question )How do i do that ?

Comment: Your problem is poor design on UI/UX. Put your code to get the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Create 4 Fragments.

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    private RadioButton radioButton;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener...
    }
}

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    private RadioButton radioButton;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener...
    }
}

public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {
    private RadioButton radioButton;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener...
    }
}

public class Fragment4 extends Fragment {
    private RadioButton radioButton;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener...
    }
}
```

Method 2: Create 1 Fragment with passing 4 different integer bundle.

```
Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
bundle1.putInt("questions1" , 1);

Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
bundle2.putInt("questions2" , 2);

Bundle bundle3 = new Bundle();
bundle3.putInt("questions3" , 3);

Bundle bundle4 = new Bundle();
bundle4.putInt("questions4" , 4);

Fragment fragment = new QuestionsFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle1);

Fragment fragment = new QuestionsFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle2);

Fragment fragment = new QuestionsFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle3);

Fragment fragment = new QuestionsFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle4);
```

and `onCreateView` in `QuestionsFragment` use `Bundle bundle1 = getArguments();` for get integer flags.